# Geoserver FTL style in IE not rendering

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am using the WMS GEt Feature Info feature in Geoserver. I created an inner ftl (content.ftl), using the header and footer ftl as it is. The WMS Get Feature Info will go into a basic Openlayers popup.

Example styling that I have for the  info table created by the ftl :

```
table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding:.2em .1em;
}
```

In IE 8, the popup does not show with any styling. it seems I need to declare and use those styles in the map page itself. It works fine with other browser.

Any ideas why?